# Return the Inverse of Tuples from an INNER JOIN Query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the remaining tuples from a query. In this case, course_id 3 and 4 from courses because the user admin@ has NOT taken these (they've only taken 1 and 2). The tables are already joined nicely and queries are working when I try a LEFT JOIN ...

```
select course_name from courses LEFT OUTER JOIN users_courses ON users_courses.user_course_id = courses.course_id where users_courses.user_email = "admin@---.com";
```

But this returns the courses 1 and 2, not 3 and 4

[image]

Comment: check the answer again, sorry for that erorr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do another thing by getting all of the courses that is not exists in the courses list for this user like this

```
select course_name from courses where course_id not in (select user_course_id from users_courses where user_email = 'admin@....')
```

### update

forget to add the column name `course_id`

Comment: you are welcome :), and sorry for my error

Answer (score 0):

Ah! I misunderstood what you were after. Joseph's method will work, but, as a rule, you should try to avoid "in(select...".

To knock-out the courses the admin has taken, just add a null condition:

```
select course_name from courses LEFT OUTER JOIN users_courses
ON users_courses.user_course_id = courses.course_id
and users_courses.user_email = "admin@---.com"
where users_courses.course_id is null;
```

Comment: Thanks for this Tom... it's returning all 4 tuples from courses though...any ideas?